# Website freezes on all browsers on iPhone 12

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, core-ui

I have a website built using free CoreUI React template (https://coreui.io/demos/react/4.0/free/#/dashboard).
When the site is visited on any browser (tested with Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Edge) on iPhone, website completely freezes from time to time (cannot scroll or click anything) or lower half of the website is white when scrolled down.
iOS and all browsers are updated to latest versions.
Other websites work ok on the device. Works fine on iPhone 13 and 14 devices.
No issues on Windows / Apple desktops / laptops or Android devices either.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "CoreUI Free React Admin Template",
  "homepage": ".",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "The CoreUI Team (https://github.com/orgs/coreui/people)",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "changelog": "auto-changelog --starting-version 3.0.0 --commit-limit false --hide-credit",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:cov": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand"
  },
  "config": {
    "coreui_library_short_version": "4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/chartjs": "^3.0.0",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^4.0.5",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.1.0",
    "@coreui/icons-react": "2.0.0",
    "@coreui/react": "4.0.0",
    "@coreui/react-chartjs": "2.0.0",
    "@coreui/utils": "^1.3.1",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.5.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.18.3",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "generate-password": "^1.7.0",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react-select": "^5.7.1",
    "react-select-search": "^4.1.6",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "redux": "4.1.1",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.6",
    "yup": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "auto-changelog": "~2.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.43.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10",
    "npm": ">=6"
  }
}
```

**.browserslistrc**

```
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#readme

>= 0.5%
last 2 major versions
not dead
Chrome >= 60
Firefox >= 60
Firefox ESR
iOS >= 12
Safari >= 12
not Explorer <= 11
```

Backend API built using Laravel Lumen.
Any help appreciated. Thanks.